# Is there an XPath equivilent for Linq to XML?

Tags: linq, xpath, linq-to-xml

I have been using Linq to XML for a few hours and while it seems lovely and powerful when it comes to loops and complex selections, it doesn't seem so good for situations where I just want to select a single node value which XPath seems to be good at.

I may be missing something obvious here but is there a way to use XPath and Linq to XML together without having to parse the document twice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can still use XPath, with the [`XPathEvaluate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.xpathevaluate.aspx), [`XPathSelectElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.xpathselectelement.aspx) and [`XPathSelectElements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.xpathselectelements.aspx) extension methods. You can also call [`CreateNavigator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.createnavigator.aspx) to create an `XPathNavigator`.