# Extracting an XML element from an XML file using XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have the following XML document:

```
  <MimeType>
     <Extension>.aab</Extension>
     <Value>application/x-authorware-</Value>
  </MimeType>
  <MimeType>
     <Extension>.aam</Extension>
     <Value>application/x-authorware-</Value>
  </MimeType>
```

The whole document contains about 700 entries. How can I extract a single `MimeType` element using **XPath** and populate it into a strongly typed C# `MimeType` object?

Comment: Are you forced not using .NET 3.5?  If you can use .NET 3.5 I would use XDocument and Linq to Xml you will find it simpler than XPath.

Comment: Not necessarily. It's better to use a combination of both: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294386/is-there-an-xpath-equivilent-for-linq-to-xml

Comment: yes forced into a .net 2 corner.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectsinglenode.aspx).

Example:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("yourXmlFileName");
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("yourXpath");
```

Then you can access `node.ChildNodes` in order to get the values you want (example):

```
string extension = node.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
string value = node.ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
```

And then use those values when constructing your MimeType object.

**Edit: Some XPath info.** 
There are some really good XPath tutorials out there, try [here](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp) and [here](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathtutorial.php). The [W3C recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) itself can be a bit overwhelming.
For your example, you could try using the following XPath to select the first `MimeType` node in the document (where `root` is whatever the name of your root element):

```
string xPath = "root/MimeType[1]"
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Donut's snippet sums it all!  It's hardly more difficult than that. You may want to check my reply to the the SO posting at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440184/how-to-display-value-in-log-file-from-an-xml-file/1440642 for a longer snippet indicative of error conditions, what's returned when not found etc.

Comment: ok I'll give this a go... any chance of getting an XPath example? Sorry to be cheeky?

Comment: Yep, added some XPath info (links + simple example) to my answer - hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The following method should provide a framework for getting the MIME Type here

```
public MimeType RunXPath(string mimeType)
{
  XmlNode node = _xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(
    string.Format("//MimeType/Extension[text()="{0}"]/ancestor::MimeType", mimeType));
  foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
  {
    // Extract the relevant nodes and populate the Mime Type here...
  }

  return ...
}
```

The trick is to find the MimeType based on the text in the extension, then retrieve the ancestor of MimeType for this match.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on [the answer by @MiffTheFox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1444824/1497596), you can use **XPath** together with **LINQ to XML**. Here's an example based on your sample data.

**1)** First, the namespaces you'll need:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
```

**2)** Load your XML document into an `XElement`:

```
XElement rootElement = XElement.Parse(xml);
```

**3)** Define your XPath location path:

```
// For example, to locate the 'MimeType' element whose 'Extension'
// child element has the value '.aam':
//
//     ./MimeType[Extension='.aam']

string extension = ".aam";
string locationPath = String.Format("./MimeType[Extension='{0}']", extension);
```

**4)** Pass the location path to `XPathSelectElement()` to select the element of interest:

```
XElement selectedElement = rootElement.XPathSelectElement(locationPath);
```

**5)** Finally, extract the MimeType value that is associated with the extension:

```
var mimeType = (string)selectedElement.Element("Value");
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the classes in the [System.Xml.XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.aspx) namespace.

[Tutorials from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87274khy.aspx)